# Hibernate HQL: select records that match two values at the same time

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a table in a DB that I cannot modify, and I have a list of pairs of values  that I have to use in order to select the records from that table that exactly match both the values in the list.

For example my list of pairs consists of `('A1', 'A2')`, `('B1', 'B2')`, `('C1', 'C2')`, and my table consists of the following data

```
--------------------------
| ID | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
--------------------------
| 1  | 'A1'    | 'A2'    |
| 2  | 'B1'    | 'B2'    |
| 3  | 'A1'    | 'B2'    |
| 4  | 'B1'    | 'A2'    |
| 5  | 'C1'    | 'C2'    |
--------------------------
```

The correct result set should be

```
1, 'A1', 'A2'
2, 'B1', 'B2'
5, 'C1', 'C2'
```

which means that records like

```
3, 'A1', 'B2'
4, 'B1', 'A2'
```

should not be in it.

How do I achieve such a result using HQL?
Performance is an obstacle in my situation, this is why a solution implemented via concatenation of values is not viable for me.

**EDIT:**

if this can help, the Java entity is very simple and it looks like this:

```
package org.example;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class ExampleEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "COLUMN1")
    private String column1;

    @Column(name = "COLUMN2")
    private String column2;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getColumn1() {
        return column1;
    }

    public void setColumn1(String column1) {
        this.column1 = column1;
    }

    public String getColumn2() {
        return column2;
    }

    public void setColumn2(String column2) {
        this.column2 = column2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the logic by which you chose `'A1', 'A2'` to appear in the result and not `'A1', 'B2'`?

Comment: it's what the software I'm working on needs. A result like `'A1', 'B2'` would not be correct

Comment: Great.  Now just give codeable logic for that and maybe somone can answer your question.

Comment: What do you mean? What info should I add in order to help people with their answers?

Comment: The record `1, 'A1', 'A2'` appears in the result because both the values `'A1'` and `'A2'` are contained in the same pair within the list

Comment: About your information: you must concatenate conditions in AND and OR as follow: column1 = 'a1' and column2 = 'a2' or column1 ='b1' and column2 = 'b2' ... and so on

Comment: @Joe Taras my pairs might be hundreds, is this viable?

Comment: @FabrizioRoman I completely misread your question +1.  Can you put these pairs into a temporary table?

Comment: @FabrizioRoman: In your logic, can we tell the first letter of two columns is the same?

Comment: I'm quite new to Hibernate and also to this project I'm working on in particular. Unfortunately I don't know if and how I can use temporary tables in this particular case

Comment: @Joe Taras no, they are the same only in this example. In a real world situation their values are completely unrelated

Comment: @FabrizioRoman: So, if you can add in a separated table these combinations, you can use a JOIN, otherwise you must write a condition with AND / OR

Answer (score 1):

I try to resume the possible solutions, considering comments in the question.

**Pay attention**

In these solutions, I'll write in SQL because I don't know your objects, but these query can be re-write in HQL if you write your object structures

**Solution 1**

Consider ONLY input data set

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE column1 = 'A1' AND column2 = 'A2'
OR column1 = 'B1' AND column2 = 'B2'
OR column1 = 'C1' AND column2 = 'C2'
```

**Solution 2**

If you can create a separated table with good couple, as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE okcouples (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10))

SELECT yt.*
FROM yourtable yt
JOIN okcouples oc
    ON yt.column1 = oc.col1
    AND yt.column2 = oc.col2
```

**Solution 3**

This is the same scenario of Solution 2 (create a separated table) but instead of JOIN you can use EXISTS clause, as follow:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable yt
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 'OK'
    FROM okcouples oc
    WHERE oc.col1 = yt.column1
    AND oc.col2 = yt.column2)
```

Comment: I added the entity that refers to the table I gave you as an example, if this can be of any help